# How to export one column from multiple data.frames from a list,

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got multiple data.frames (26) in a list. The dfs have the same structure, but I would like working/exporting only two different columns. I can export all the dfs to individual dfs

```
for(i in filelist){
    list2env(setNames(filelist, paste0("names(filelist[[i]])",
             seq_along(filelist))), envir = parent.frame())}
```

I can delete a column from all the dfs

```
for(i in seq_along(filelist)){filelist[[i]]$V5 = NULL}
```

but I cannot export the other columns individually. From a single data.frame it simply works:

```
token_out_mk_totatyafiak_02.txt = out_mk_totatyafiak_02.txt["V2"]
type_out_mk_totatyafiak_02.txt = out_mk_totatyafiak_02.txt["V1"]
```

When I tried these

```
for(i in seq_along(filelist)){n[[i]] <- filelist[[i]]$V2}

for(i in seq_along(filelist)){
    sapply(filelist, function(x) n <- filelist[[i]]$V2)
   }
```

the most I achieved, that I could read in all the 26 dfs the second column of the last df.

The V2 looks like:

```
        V2

1       az

2        a

3   f
ekete

4     folt
```

(and so on, these are hungarian short stories... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your desired results, you have several options.

If you want a new list, with your data frames containing only one specific column.

```
new_filelist <- 
  lapply(filelist, function(df){
    df["V2"]
  })
```

If you want to export to a file one specific column for all data frames, in separate files (in this case, .txt files).

This requires your data frames in your list to be named. In case they are not, you can replace `names(filelist)` for `1:length(filelist)`.

```
lapply(names(filelist), function(df){
  df_filename <- paste0(df, ".txt")
  write.table(filelist[[df]]["V2"], df_filename)
})
```

If you wan to assign to new objects in your enviroment one specific column for all your data frames.

Again, this requires your data frames to be named.

```
lapply(names(filelist), function(df){
  assign(df, filelist[[df]]["V2"], envir = .GlobalEnv)
})
```